# Changing properties to effect all objects in scene

Tags: python, game-engine, properties

How do you change the value of all properties among objects that share the same property?

Warning this code does not work, just an idea.

## Example:

```
baseScale = 1.0
size = 2.0

objName = scene.objects["ALL OBJECTS"]
pName = scene.objects["ALL OBJECTS"]["scale"]

objName[pName] = baseScale

for obj in objName:    
  if obj.property == "scale":
    obj.property = size
```

Basically I'm just trying to find a way of changing one property and having it effect all objects in the scene with the new value.

Comment: you talking about game properties? Because that is very different then just a properties in blender.

Comment: yeah, the blender game engine is what I'm looking for.